# is there a limit on querying the parse installation class?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am developing an Android app using parse as the backend. I am using it to send push notifications to a specific device, however I need to query the installation class to get the specific device so that I can send the push.

```
ParsePush parsePush = new ParsePush();
ParseQuery pQuery = ParseIntallation.query(); // <-- Installation query
pQuery.whereEqualTo("username", currentUser.getUsername()); // <-- you'll probably want to target someone that's not the current user, so modify accordingly
parsePush.sendMessageInBackground("Only for special people", pQuery);
```

My question is, if I have more than 10,000 users, will parse limit the query to 100 or 1000 users? I have heard this is the limit to querying the parse database class.

Answer (score 1):

I sent push notifications to about 30k users 10 min ago, and it works.

By default, you can query 100 objects at a time when you use function like findInBackground(), and by setLimit(1000) you can query at most 1000 objects. But the limitation is not for sendMessageInBackground().

Comment: Thank you for the reply @iForests, you used the method above for querying the installation class to send the push? and may i ask how many user objects you have in your installation class?

Comment: Yes. There are about 30k objects in _Installation class.

Answer (score 1):

The query which you give as input to push notification by cloud code (or push query as commonly known) will not be affected by the parse query limit. As per parse representative  -

"The default query limit of 100 applies to the find() operation specifically. This limit does not apply to queries used to target push notifications. There's no upper bound on how many installations can be targeted by a single push query (otherwise, it wouldn't be possible to send a broadcast push notification!)"